Quadratic form minimization: 2 variables
% Preview source code for paragraph 0
Suppose that there is the positive semidefinite (antisymetric) matrix
$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & -2 & 0 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & \cdots & -1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{array}\right],
$$
$x,y$ are the vectors, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
How to find vectors $x,y$ minimizing the quadratic function
$$
\min\left\Vert x^{T}Ay\right\Vert _{2}^{2},\qquad\mathrm{s.t}.:\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{2}=\left\Vert y\right\Vert _{2}=1.
$$
I tried to perform the SVD decomposition $A=USV$,
then
\begin{align*}
\min\left\Vert x^{T}Ay\right\Vert _{2}^{2} & =\min\left\Vert x^{T}USVy\right\Vert _{2}^{2},\\
 & =\min\left\Vert (U^{T}x)^{T}SVy\right\Vert _{2}^{2}.
\end{align*}
However, I do not know how to continue in solving 2D optimization problems with quadratic forms.
Thanks for your help.

What a strange question. If $A$ is anti-symmetric, then $x^TAx=0$ for every vector $x$. Therefore the minimum is zero.

@ user1551: Thanks for your comment, but the quadratic form is x^T * A * y

@justik What happens if you choose $y=x?$

@ greg: In my opinion, we obtain a line $y=x$ sampled by n-points. Then, the quadratic form $\left\Vert x^{T}Ay\right\Vert _{2}^{2}=0$ which is minimum.

@ greg: In my opinion, $y=kx$, where $k\in\mathbb{R}$, might be the solution. However, ho to prove it.

If you show $x^T A y=0$ that's a global minimum, because the function you're minimizing cannot be less than zero.

Or... Are you trying to find all pairs $x, y$ that minimize $(x^T Ay)^2)$, not just some?

@ Alex K: Good comment.... I would like to find all pairs... In my opinion, $ x^{T}Ay$ can also be negative. This is the least squares problem.
